# Calculate prediction values for linear curve estimation for next 5 intervals

Tags: estimation, prediction, curve-fitting, nonlinear

Below is my code with sample data as in screen shot ; in that i got response for only 21 to 33.
My requirement is to get response for 34, 35 , 36, 37

### Sample Data

### [image]

Below is R code

linearCurve<-lm(Month ~ Value, data = data)
CurveResponse<-cbind(predict(linearCurve,type="response"))

Comment: Where is your Month variable in the sample data?

Comment: First column is "Month" i.e. 21 to 33 and Second column is "Value" i.e. 6591.35 to 8575.81

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in R using the `predict` function. For ease I used Month as predictor and Value as outcome. In the vector `new` are the predicted values as a function of Month. Please see also the plot that shows the projected values on the regression line.

```
data=data.frame(Month=c(21:33), Value=c(6591.69, 6579.62, 7133.84, 6955.89, 7573.27, 7556.87, 7751.17, 8001.76, 8399.5, 8560.36, 8517.53, 8602.57, 8575.81))

attach(data)

fit1<-lm(Value~Month, data=data)

new<-predict(fit1, data.frame(Month=(c(34,35,36))))

plot(Value~Month, data, col="red", xlim=c(20,36), ylim=c(6000,10000))
abline(fit1, col="orange", lwd=2)
abline(v=c(34,35,36), lty=6)
points(34, new[1], col="blue")
points(35, new[2], col="blue")
points(36, new[3], col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution , it's work for me.
but i  need dynamic variable in that. Below code doesn't work for me , i don't know why ?
[code]
data = read.csv("c:/curve.csv", header=TRUE)
attach(data)
fit1<-lm(data[,2]~data[,1], data=data)
predict(fit1, data.frame(MONTH_=(c(34,35,36,37))))
[/code]